# Include detail in table of figures that is not in the caption

Tags: ms-word

I've got completely stuck on something that should be trivial: I am working with MS Word 2003, and am putting together a table of figures. I need to have more detail in the table of figures than I have in the caption. For example, in the caption I have:

Fig 1: John and Jenny in London

and in the table of figures I need to the source and accessed date:

Fig 1: John and Jenny in London, available at www.johnandjenny.com, accessed 03/09/2013

I have tried using hidden text in the caption, but the hidden text is not included in the table of figures. The only other thing I can think of is to include all of the detail in the caption, but make the bit that I don't want to show white. This is not ideal, because sometimes the additional detail is several lines long, and this will create a dead space in the caption.

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  Is the table also in the word document or are you just using the word doc as the source for your table?

Comment: The table is in the word document. Added all of the image captions using Insert|Reference|Caption, and then added the table using Insert|Reference|Tables and indexes|Table of Figures.

Comment: Unless there's programming involved, you might have better luck with this question at http://superuser.com/.  As stated the question isn't clear how you're accessing the document.  Either programatically or manually through the word interface.

Comment: I will do that, thank you. This is not a programming question - I'm accessing the document through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - didn't find your question on SU, so posting my answer here ...

Mark your complete caption and press Alt+Shift+X to create an index entry {XE ...} where in the subentry you add your "hidden" text. Then - instead of a table of figures - create an index and add the \r switch to get index entry and subentry on one line.

example:
[image]